# cacls.exe php en windows

Tags: php, windows

estuve buscando, pero no encontré mucha información al respecto.

Necestio asignar pemisos a directorios en windows desde PHP.
Me dijeron que como mod no sirve en windows use cacls.exe, pero no encuentro la forma de implementarlo.

Existe alguna guía oficial (o no) para seguir paso a paso?

Comment: Creo que tu solucion seria crear un localhost (dominio local) con UwAmp, si no era la respuesta que buscabas, te recomiendo que formules tu pregunta con mas argumentos y que brindaras mas informacion, asi a nosotros no se nos hace tan complejo esta conversacion.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que `chmod` no te funciona en Windows? http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Según la documentación oficial, sí http://php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php

Comment: No hablo del parámetro `mode`, hablo de crear el directorio y posteriormente utilizar `chmod` y aplicarle los permisos

Comment: Cómo hago para aplicar los permisos? Porque por lo que veo chmod debe usar el parámetro mode, que entiendo es donde van los permisos. Perdón la ignorancia, no tengo mucha experiencia en php

Answer (score 0):

Para `Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8 (y superiores)` debes usar [`icacls`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Ejemplos en `PHP` usando [`operadores de ejecución`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.execution.php) y [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php)

- Visualizar los usuarios y privilegios:

  ```
  var_dump(`icacls test`);
  ```
- Otorgar control completo al usuario `Marcos`:

  ```
  var_dump(`icacls test /grant Marcos:(F)`);
  ```
- Quitar control completo al usuario `Marcos`:

  ```
  var_dump(`icacls test /deny Marcos:(F)`);
  ```